# Spots on lemons

Tags: lemons

I've got quite a few lemons covered in dark spots. They don't seem to go deep and the lemons don't seem to be spoiled inside. I've never picked lemons before, so I'm wondering - are they safe to eat?

(the spring just started here)

[image]
[image]

Requested follow-up: The tree looks mostly ok. There are few leaves which don't look healthy and they're mostly around the lemons with spots. The spots on the leaves look either very similar to the ones on lemons:

[image]

Or small white dots (mould-like?):

[image]

Otherwise it looks ok. Bark is fine and there are no persistent bugs that I can see around. Very few leaves have been nibbled on - likely a long while ago.

Comment: Hi viraptor! How is your lemon tree doing? Are the leaves and bark in good health? Do you see any bugs or other insects on either the lemons or leaves? If anything at all is out of the ordinary with the plant, some more pictures would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Thanks - I added the requested photos. The bark doesn't show anything wrong with it. There are no bugs that I can see (some leaves have been nibbled on, but it's very few). Leaves as described above.

Comment: My lemons are like yours. I just think my climate is much too wet for lemon (or just commercial lemons hame more chemicals). But I think a real answer from an expert could erase also my doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it might be [citrus black spot](http://www.idtools.org/id/citrus/diseases/factsheet.php?name=Citrus%20black%20spot)

> Leaf - older lesions are small, round, sunken necrotic spots with gray centers. The lesions are bordered with a dark brown ring. Young lesions are small, reddish, and slightly raised. A yellow halo can be associated with the lesions. Foliar lesions are most commonly seen on lemons.

and the fruit

> Hard spot (1) is the most typical and diagnostic symptom of black spot as the fruit mature, often appearing around color change. The lesions are circular depressions with a diameter of 3-10 mm (0.12 - 0.4 inch). The brick red lesions have tan to grey centers with a distinct brown to black margin. Pycnidia are usually, but not always, present in the lesions.

Comment: It does look similar. There doesn't seem to be any mention if that makes them not safe for eating :(

Comment: safe to eat .. just reduces the tree productivity.